# How to view the imported dataset in sas enterprise miner

Tags: sas, enterprise-miner

I have imported a dataset into SAS Enterprise miner using the file import node.Now how can I explore and view the imported data set within SAS Enterprise miner?

Comment: Usually double click it?

Comment: Double click doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the *Data Sources* and click *Explore*.

[image: Click here to view the image]

Answer (score 0):

At the place where you can see Data Sources, right mouse click on the data set you want to explore. At the drop down menu, select Explore. You will get a sample, though, not the full view